# expected result of iswspace(160)

Tags: c

I'm seeing different results for iswspace(160) depending on which compiler I use. That should be the non-breaking-space (U+0020), and I was expecting a non-zero result, or at least the same result independent of compiler. However, gcc and clang on Linux return 0, msvc on Windows returns 8. Tested both on my own machines and at https://rextester.com/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>

int main() {
printf("%d\n", iswspace(160));
return 0;
}
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/iswspace, it's gcc and clang that are wrong: "ISO 30112 defines POSIX space characters as Unicode characters U+0009..U+000D, U+0020, [...]"

The C99 standard is less specific: "The iswspace function tests for any wide character that corresponds to a locale-specific set of white-space wide characters for which none of iswalnum, iswgraph, or iswpunct is true."

Is there a canonical list of values for which iswspace should return true, anywhere? Is this a bug in either compiler, or are they just interpreting the standard differently, and there is no "correct" answer?

Comment: Thanks. My takeaway here is that I can't use iswspace in code that I want to be portable between msvc and gcc, and that if I want to trim all spaces (including non-breaking) from the start and end of a word, it was the wrong function to use.